# How can I change the dtype of a distribution in Tensorflow Probability?

Tags: tensorflow-probability, dtype, probabilistic-programming

Is there any possibility of changing the dtype of a `tensorflow_probability.distribution`, either on instantiation or with a respective setter()?

I want to use `tf.float64` instead of the standard `tf.float32` but could not find any way to do this, since the `dtype`-attribute is not directly accessible and `tf.cast()` does not work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally just need to pass some numerical parameter explicitly, tf.cast or np.cast to f64.

Comment: But this would be a rather inelegant solution, always casting to f64? I thought it would probably be better (i.e. more numerically accurate) to have tf also work with f64 internally.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your answer. You meant passing any distribution parameters, e.g. the mu of a normal distribution, casted to the dtype I want the distribution to be, right? This is now working for me, thank you!